# Prove that if $\alpha$ is any cycle of length $n$, and $\beta$ is any transposition, then ${\alpha, \beta}$ generates $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

[image: questions]

Question 6 from the above set of exercises has me a bit stumped. I see that you can rotate then relabel $\alpha = (a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n)$ such that $\alpha = (1 2 \cdots n)$ and $\beta = (1 m)$ — that *almost* makes the problem reducible to the result of question 5, but not quite, since we do not know that $m = 2$, and this fact is crucial in the proof for question 5. I would appreciate any tips.

Comment: The hint from 5 can be adapted when $m-1$ is relatively prime to $n$, but otherwise I'm not sure how to approach the problem.

Comment: @DavidPeterson If you do more relabelling, it will throw off the order of the numbers (labels) in the cycle. That's what I wrote "I see that you can rotate then relabel" — since this is the closest you can get through relabelling, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @DavidPeterson I thought you might be interested in knowing that your assertion was incorrect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Statement 6 is not true as stated. [For example](https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/generating-the-symmetric-group-with-a-transposition-and-a-maximal-length-cycle/), $(1\ \ 3)$ and $(1\ \ 2\ \ 3\ \ 4)$ fail to generate $S_4$. In particular, the subgroup generated by these two elements is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_4$ of order $8$.

---

In fact, we can see that for $n>2$, $\alpha = (1\cdots n)$ and $\beta = (1\ \ m)$ will generate $S_n$ if and only if $n$ and $m-1$ are coprime.

For the $\Longleftarrow$ direction, it suffices to repeat the construction in the hint for part 5.

In particular, we have
$$
\alpha^{m-1}(1\ \ m)\alpha^{1 - m} = (m\quad 2m - 1), \quad (1\ \ m)(m\quad 2m - 1)(1 \ \ m) = (1\ \ 2m - 1).
$$
Here, $2m - 1$ is taken modulo $n$, as are any further operations here.  With that, we have constructed every transposition of the form $(1\quad  1 + k(m-1))$.  However, because $m-1$ and $n$ are relatively prime, we see that every element of $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ can be written in the form $k(m-1)$ for some $k$. So, we have constructed every transposition of the form $(1\ \ k)$ (for $k \in \{1,\dots,n\}$), which was precisely the point of the hint.

For the $\implies$ direction: let $d = \gcd(m-1,n)$. Note that $\alpha, \beta$ have the property that whenever $i \equiv j \pmod d$, then it holds that $\alpha(i) \equiv \alpha(j)$ and $\beta(i) \equiv \beta(j)$, modulo $d$. It follows that every element of the subgroup generated by $\alpha$ and $\beta$ also has this property. We therefore see that the subgroup generated by $\alpha$ and $\beta$ does not include all of $S_n$ because, for instance, the element $(1\ \ 2)$ does not have this property.

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right. I actually thought of this example in passing, though somehow didn't give it proper attention. (Well, the more general case when the cycle is of even length $2n$ and transposition contains the first and $n + 1$'th elements.? Could you kindly expand your answer with a comment about $m - 1$ needing to be coprime to $n$? Then I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Well I can see that $m-1$ being coprime is sufficient, but while I suspect that it is also necessary I don't see a way to prove this.

Comment: @Noldorin Actually, the justification turned out not to be all that complicated. See my latest edit.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Extremely  helpful answer sir (at least for me) . Can you please answer as to why it is said (in referrence to the link you provided) that " Any automorphism of $\{1,2,3,...p\}$ induces an automorphsim of $S_p$ (in fact an inner automorphism)" . Won't that be "Any permutation of $\{1,2,3,..p\}$..."?

Comment: @user710290 I think that the author is saying that for any permutation $\pi$, the map $\sigma \mapsto \pi \sigma \pi^{-1}$ is an automorphism of $S_p$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Formalising the proof in the $\Longleftarrow$ direction ended up being a bit convoluted. First, I inductively constructed the set $\{(k (k + m - 1)_n): 1 \leq k \leq n\}$. Then I showed this set has size $n$, using a bit of modular arithmetic, given the assumption $n$ and $m - 1$ are coprime. Finally, I inductively constructed the set $\{(1k): 1 \leq k \leq n\}$ from the first set, using the hint in Q5. Is this right? Is there no more efficient way to go about it?

Comment: @Noldorin see my latest edit.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks, that proof is definitely shorter than mine (though I think both work).

Comment: A quick note to anyone reading this: the proof in the reverse direction is very nice, but the use of a 1-based counting system (as in the question) makes the modular arithmetic very awkward, so it's better to just rephrase it in terms of and 0-based system, for which the condition is naturally that $n$ and $m$ (rather than $m - 1$) are coprime.

Comment: Also, I believe that the group element $(1d)$ always fails to possess the required property if $n$ and $m$ (or $m - 1$ depending on your counting system) are not coprime. Take $i = 1, j = d + 1$ to see this.