# Do any maximal-length odd cycle and any incommensurate odd cycle generate the alternating group?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups

Let $\sigma,\tau \in A_n$ be any $n$-cycle and any $m$-cycle where $1 < m < n$ and $m,n$ are odd and have no common factor (here $A_n$ is the alternating group -- so $\sigma$ is a maximal-length cycle). Let $G = \langle \sigma,\tau \rangle \subseteq A_n$ be the subgroup they generate.

**Questions:**

1. Do we have $G = A_n$?
2. If the answer to (1) is "no" in general, then does that change if we assume that $m,n$ are prime?

Comment: What does "no common factor" mean? There is no unique factorization of cycles....

Comment: Sorry, that's meant to be read that $m$ and $n$ have no common factor.

Comment: Oh, I see; so $\gcd(m,n)=1$. Sorry for misparsing that.

Comment: I think the condition that $n$ is prime is sufficient, but the answer is no in general. For instance:
$$
n = 50, \quad \sigma = (1\ \ 2 \ \ \cdots \ \ 50), \quad \tau = (5\ \ 10 \ \ 15).
$$
Note that for each permutation $\pi$ in the subgroup generated by $\sigma, \tau,$ we have $i \equiv j \pmod 5 \implies \pi(i) \equiv \pi(j) \pmod 5$.

Comment: For the case where $n$ is prime, I think it suffices to consider 
$$
\sigma = (1\ \ 2 \ \ \cdots \ \ n), \quad \tau = (1\ \ 2 \ \ \cdots \ \ m).
$$

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3741717/81360) is related.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks. I suppose I did say that $m,n$ should be odd, but your example can be trivially modified to have $n = 25$; the subgroup generated by $\sigma,\tau$ preserves the residue mod 5 of any difference $i - j$, which presumably $A_{25}$ does not. Regarding your second comment, obviously we can always assume that $\sigma = (1,2,\dots,n)$, but how does one then normalize $\tau$ to be $(1,2,\dots,m)$ when $n$ is prime?

Comment: @tcamps I stated that a bit prematurely; I'm actually not sure it's possible

Comment: If $n$ is even then the cycles of length $n$ are not in $A_n$. So $n=50$ is not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result is true when $m$ and $n$ are both prime, but I can only see how to prove it by using the classification of finite simple groups.

There is an old result of Jordan from 1873, that almost does it: if a (finite) primitive permutation group $G$ of degree $n$ contains a $p$-cycle with $p$ prime and $p \le n-3$, then $G$ is $A_n$ or $S_n$.

We can apply that here with $m=p$, because the degree is prime and the action is clearly transitive, so it is primitive. So we only have to consider the case when $m=n-2$ and $n,m$ are twin primes.

It is easy to see that $G$ must act triply transitively in that case and, using the classification of finite simple groups, we can list the possibilities for $G$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698327), for example), and check that none of them have degree $n$ with $n-2$ prime.

Comment: Thanks! Where can I read more about this result of Jordan? (I think it's actually more relevant to me than my original question!)

Comment: Actually, there must be a bit more to the statement of Jordan's theorem, right? As it's stated, there's nothing prohibiting us from taking $n=9$, $G = \langle (1,2,\dots,9) \rangle \cong C_9$, and the $p=3$-cycle to be $(1,4,7)$.

Comment: It's Theorem 13.9 of Wielandt's book on Finite Permutation Groups. Your example is imprimitive (i.e. it preserves a nontrivial partition).

Comment: Sorry, I'm speaking nonsense.